No puedo instalar ningún Framework, ni siquiera ninguna actualización de npm: npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
Intento instalar Angular, Vue o React y siempre me ocurre el mismo error.
Al principio parece que la instalación inició y todo pero luego de un rato me da error:
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent request to https:// registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2Fcli failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOENT registry.npmjs.org
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Jorge413\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-28T14_02_37_984Z-debug-0.log


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Si no podes instalar nada de nada, el problema es de tu red, o de algo por ahi... que dice el debug?? hay mas info ahi??

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

No has dicho que has intentando, una búsqueda rápida indica que puede ser a) Problemas de red b) Que npm no encuentra el archivo para descargar. Tienes que revisar el log y compartir que dice.
